# validating the Regex Matcher.find() does not find the accurate key and values

Tags: java, regex, jakarta-ee, pattern-matching, regex-group

I had written a method to validate the input string with the Regex
and i build regex for the every input string 
and if any match found i am extracting key and values

```
public Matcher matchRegExPattrenWithInputString(String inputString) {
        LOGGER.info("Mathcing the Input String " +inputString);
        Matcher matcher = null;
        for (Pattern pattern : commandRegExCacher.getRegExPattrenCache()) {
            matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
            System.out.println(inputString);
            System.out.println("Matching String"+matcher);
            LOGGER.info("Mathcing pattern" +matcher);
            if (matcher != null && matcher.find()) {
                LOGGER.debug("Input String matched ");
                break;
            } else {
                matcher = null;
            }
        }
```

commandRegExCacher.getRegExPattrenCache() is a map where i am building patterns for all the required commands

```
pattern= (?i)(^\s?)(Watch\b\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\\^$*+?.()|\[\]{}'"\s]+)$ 
 pattern= (?i)(^\s?)(Watch Channel\b\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\\^$*+?.()|\[\]{}'"\s]+)$ 
 pattern= (?i)(^\s?)(Tune\b\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\\^$*+?.()|\[\]{}'"\s]+)$ 
 pattern= (?i)(^\s?)(Tune To\b\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\\^$*+?.()|\[\]{}'"\s]+)$ 
 pattern=(?i)(^\s?)(goto\b\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9\u0590-\u05fe-\/\\^$*+?.()|\[{}'"\s]+)$
 pattern=(?i)(^\s?)(pi\b\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9\u0590-\u05fe-\/\\^$*+?.()|\[\{}'"\s]+)$
```

So there are so many patterns created on the required commands .
when user inputs string , i am iterating through the map of patterns and checking if that exists , When searching for **Watch Channel** , if it finds **watch Pattern**  , condition will be true and it returns the only Watch Pattern.

pattern= (?i)(^\s?)(Watch\b\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9/\^$*+?.()|[]{}'"\s]+)$

So what is happening is it takes watch as the key and channel start sports as value

So any pointers to handle this.

Comment: Reorder your regular expressions so that the most precise ones are checked first.

Comment: This is a good example of using regular expressions where they are not needed.  An alternative which is both faster and easier to read is `if (inputString.trim().toLowerCase().startsWith("watch channel ")) remainder = inputString.trim().substring(13).trim();`

Comment: @VGR i Don't want to hard code the values , There are n number of values that i am building pattern ,so whichever input string comes i just need to validate that String exists against the built patterns .

Comment: You don’t have to hard-code them.  I was just providing an example.  You could just as easily do `if (inputString.trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + " ")) remainder = inputString.trim().substring(prefix.length()).trim();`

Comment: @Phylogenesis Can you please brief me how can i reorder the regex

Comment: You can use https://regex101.com/ to test your regular expressions. Note that you only use single backslashes for that when you need double in your Java.

Answer (score 0):

Tune To , Watch Channel commands were not working because when iterating the Tune Pattern comes first , it matches with the list of pattern so it was validating with the Tune pattern first and it return the same , So i have resolved it by Taking the LinkedHsMap and i inserted keys with the bigger length .
so that the String with max length iterates first .